# Cannot login to MySQL in MAMP via the command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, mamp

I open the command line & go to my MAMP binary directory like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Next type in:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

And I get a mysql “command not found” error

I also tried this:

```
mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
```

And I get the same mysql “command not found” error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are doing the correct thing by going to this directory:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Calling MySQL like this won’t work:

```
mysql
```

That will attempt to run the system binary, script, etc… outside of the directory even if it exists or not.

To run a program that exists in a directory you are now in you should prepend `./` to the command and then run it like this:

```
./mysql -u root -p
```

Or you can even run it like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```